# Add Variables in Bulk for ortools

Tags: python, or-tools, runtime

I am using the Python `ortools` to solve large LPs where the number of variables and constraints are in the hundred thousands ($10^5$). Surprisingly, it takes longer to initialize variables and declare constraints than to solve the actual LP:

| Phase | Average Time (secs) |
| --- | --- |
| Variable Initialization | 56.28 |
| Constraint Initialization | 203.73 |
| LP Solve | 116.34 |

Is there a way to lower the time to initialize variables and constraints by batching them?
For my experiments, I solve many of these LPs, so any reduction in runtime would be appreciated.

Comment: There has been some discussion here: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1020, maybe you could try it